# Shell Scripting - URL manipulation

Tags: linux, shell, debugging, url, scripting

I need to manipulate a URL from the values from a file. This is what I could do

```
var=$(grep -A2 -i "some_text" /path/to/file | grep -v "some_text" | cut -d'"' -f 4-5 | cut -d'"' -f 1 | tr -d '\n')
```

This will give output : /text/to/be/appended/to/domain

Now, I need to append the domain name to `var` value.

So I did,

```
var1="http://mydomain"
```

and then

```
echo ${var1}${var}
```

So I expect

```
http://mydomain/text/to/be/appended/to/domain
```

to be the output. But am getting just `/text/to/be/appended/to/domain`.

I guessed it'd be due to the `/` as the first char, but if i use `cut` to remove the first `/`, am getting value of `var1` as output.

Where did I go wrong?

Update (not sure if this would help even a bit, still) :

If I do `echo ${var}${var1}`, am getting `/text/to/be/appended/to/domainhttp://mydomain`

Sample entry :

```
<tr><td><a id="value">some_text</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a id="value" href="/text/to/be/appended/to/domain">2013</a></td></tr>
```

Comment: this script: #!/bin/bash

var=/text/to/be/appended/to/domain
var2="http://mydomain"

echo ${var2}${var} works on my environment.

Comment: That's right. This simple eg works well on my environment as well. Am I doing the value construction in a wrong way? But am getting the intended value in var.

Comment: try echo only var to see the value?

Comment: echoing var and var1 separately gives correct values.

Comment: can you provide the whole script code + 1 entry from your file you're parsing?

Comment: Hi, have added sample entry. Script is exactly the same as I posted in the question. ie. declared var, var1. echoed $var$var1

Comment: yep, for me too, the sample entry works on my side. The only thing that comes to mind is to make sure you have #!/bin/bash as a first line in your script :).

Comment: #!/bin/bash

var="http://mydomain"
echo $var

var1=$(grep -A2 -i "some_text" /path/to/file | grep -v "some_text" | cut -d'"' -f 4-5 | cut -d'"' -f 1 | tr -d '\n')
echo $var1

echo ${var}${var1}
this is the script

Comment: Echo to a file and open the file with a text editor. Do you still see just the path?

Comment: Ok, so when I output to a file, it is like : http://mydomain ^M/text/to/be/appended/to/domain. So now I need to remove the ^M and space between them. But why is it not getting echoed on stdout?

Comment: this line ending (^M) points that at some point the file was edited(created) in dos like environment. Use "dos2unix yourfile" to fix the problem. BOTH your script and the sample entries.

Comment: @hovanessyan Thank you, I think it worked then. This is for anyone who might encounter the same problem. I just happened to see this post and I actually don't remember why I didn't get back then. Thanks again and apologies for the late response.

Answer (score 2):

> this line ending (^M) points that at some point the file was edited(created) in dos like environment. Use "dos2unix yourfile" to fix the problem. BOTH your script and the sample entries.